# IFrame window over the flash

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe

I need to open the payment system window. Window is opened through the iFrame. In the flash (swf) generates a call to ExternalInterface

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
ExternalInterface.call("ShowWebSite", "http://myService.com/show_form?app_params=testable_app_params&format=iframe&sig=54222d8a1c2a9412b91bc0abe62e8040&ts=1296285802");
                }
```

Set parameters of the flash: params.wmode = "opaque";

Call the JS function:

```
<script laguage='javascript'> 
      function ShowWebSite(url) 
       { 
          //Try any way
          document.getElementByID('iFrameID').src=url; 
        //parent.frames['iFrameID'].location.href=url; 
        //window.frames.iFrameID.location.href=url; 
      } 
   </script> 
// to body 
 <iframe id="iFrameID" width="430" height="400" scrolling="no" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></iframe>
```

Everything should work, but the window does not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive:

```
document.getElementById()
```